Is the F function from python allowed in MySQL SQL scripts
I am trying to create a database with a table where a csv file's data will be inserted into this table. My code is written as below:
def databaseOperation(countryCode, fileList):

#establish connection to database
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  password=PASSWORD
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS COUNTRY;")

if countryCode == "*":
    
    for i in range(1):
        
        
        name = fileList[i].replace(".csv", "")
        mycursor.execute(f"CREATE TABLE {name}  (fName VARCHAR(255), sName VARCHAR(255), gender VARCHAR(255), countryCode, VARCHAR(255))")
        csv_data = csv.reader(f"C:\Coding Portfolio\Python\python and database\dataset\data\{fileList[i]}")
        for row in csv_data:
            
            mycursor.execute(
                f'INSERT INTO {name}(fName, sName, gender, countryCode)'
            )

        print("Insert Successful")

This is my first time integrating any sort of SQL database in a python script, would appreciate if any other errors or mal practice can be pointed out.
Anyways, is the f function allowed in the script for example the line mycursor.execute(f'INSERT INTO {name}(fName, sName, gender, countryCode))
If not then how should I approach create a table and inserting data while trying to use the CSV's file name.
Note: there is about 50 CSV files I need to import, each having about a few million records with one having 31 million as the highest. Second of all, as of right now the for i in range(1) is set to one so I can check that the import is successful.

FYI: Using prepared statements with mysql in python
